# My PC reboots itself after upgrading to Samsung SSD 860 evo and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, power-supply

My PC reboots itself multiple times after doing some heavy load task.. such as playing games, etc. my rig is old and im just slowly upgrading it..

My old specs were 
Windows 8.1
Intel Pentium 4400
Ram 4GB
Asus H110-D motherboard
No Video card.. 
500GB hard drive..
(A potato Computer) but it is perfectly fine.. i can play starcraft 2 with medium settings with no problems.. and company of heroes with medium to high settings with good fps.. but when i bought a samsung SSD 860 evo and fresh install windows 10. at first it is perfect fine but after a few days problems started to show up... i cant even play starcraft2 without it crashing with BSOD and cant install games because of the unarc.dll/isdone.dll error.. and company of heroes crashes on start and my cpu and memory usage is high when i open games and sometimes it automatically restarts itself after a few minutes.. the bios and drivers are up to date.. i dont know whats wrong...maybe the PSU? because im using an old TRENDSONIC LC-8600BTX 600W PSU... what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that Windows 8 DLLs and other configuration settings left over are causing the problem. Suggest you make a backup of your data, verify it matches the original source, collect all the media with your apps and drivers to install, then wipe the drive and install Windows 10 from scratch, then install your apps and restore your data.